# How to add filter to match the value in a map bin Aerospike

Tags: aerospike

I have a requirement where I have to find the record in an aerospike based on attributeId. The data in aerospike is inthe below format

```
{
 name=ABC, 
 id=xyz, 
 ts=1445879080423, 
 inference={2601=0.6}
}
```

Now I will be getting the value "2601" programatically and I should find this record based on this value. But the problem is the value is in a Map and the size of this map may be more than 1 like

```
inference={{2601=0.6},{2830=0.9},{2931=0.8}}
```

So how can I find this record using attributeId in java. Any suggestions much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little know feature of Aerospike is that, in addition to a Bin, you can define an index on:

- List values
- Map Keys
- Map Values

Using in index defined on your map keys in the "inference" bin, you will be able to query (filter) base on the key's name.

I hope this helps